# How to realize command %x() in script?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have code

```
<html>
<body>

<p>
<%= submit_tag "Compute in TJ", :type => 'button', :onclick => "javascript:tj3_com()" %>
</p>

<textarea id='placeForText' cols='70' rows='7' disabled></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
function tj3_com(){
    <% name = "#{@project.identifier.gsub(/-/,"_")}" + '-' + "#{@project.tj_version.to_s.gsub(/\./,"_")}" + '-' +'20140331_145001' + '.tjp' %>
    <% output = %x{tj3 ~/projects/name} %>
    <% outp = name %>
    document.getElementById('placeForText').innerHTML='<%= output %>';
   }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But it's not work. If I try to display variable "outp", it's work, but for "output" it's not work.

Can you tell me why it's nt work? What's wrong with this code?

Comment: If the question is about javascript, then please show the rendered html with js

Comment: @Sergey P. aka azure Here I have just html-page with included script-code. And now I want to know how use the comman %x() in html-code, because it's not work in html-code.

Comment: of course it should not work in html. html is just a markup language, it does not have any variables. You have to put some variables to javascript.

Comment: which variables? Can you give an example?